# Simple Apache2 Reverse Proxy config not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, reverse-proxy

I've installed Apache2 on 2 ubuntu 11.10 VMs and I am trying to get a very basic Reverse Proxy working.

I have nothing but the default site setup on each. I want to go to `http://server.com/app` and have it return `http://app.internal.server.com/`.

From what I have read it should all be fairly straight forward, but I have no experience with Apache so I am probably missing something!

For example, I haven't set up anything on Apache (other than the ProxyPass directives) to tell it anything about `/app`.

I enabled mod_proxy with `apache2ctl mod_proxy` and added the following to httpd.conf then restarted apache2:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /app/ http://app.internal.server.com/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://app.internal.server.com/
```

In the apache2 `error.log` I am seeing:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the proxy configuration within the default `<VirtualHost>` block in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Most of that config is inert, by the way - all you need is the `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` and potentially the `ProxyPreserveHost` if the backend server needs that.

Comment: I had to change `/app/` to `/app` otherwise it only worked with the trailing slash.. THANKS!